# Can't update my product name, PUT REST CALL

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, rest-api

I've some problems with updating the name of my product. I'm using the REST CALL API.

Here's the PHP Code

[image: Here's My PHP code]

Here's the error

[image: Here's the error]

I'm using the PUT REST CAll from product repository, to update the name of a product. Getting this error and just can't seem to find out why.

EDIT 1 : I managed to pass by this error by giving the attributesetId i use, he then threw ma an error that i needed to give the SKU in the json string, I did that, and now he throws me an error that I can't save the product, reason for this is that you can't update the SKU number because it's unique. Why do I need to add the SKU in my json file, i already gave it by with the rest call, as i add the sku after the URL ?

Answer (score 1):

Magento use Upsert for PUT request. You need provide full data to update entity.

So, get entity by id, update needed filed and use put to update it